# Using hdpi drawables in mdpi tablets without creating image copies

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my app to be as lightweight as possible. So i put all my images inside `drawable-xxhdpi` and let the Android OS to resize them.

However for the 10 inch **mdpi** tablets i want to use **hdpi** images. I know, that it is possible to create `drawable-sw720dp-mdpi` and put there **hdpi** images. But this will increase apk size, which is not the option. So, is it possible to make such a change without making drawable copies?

Comment: I really don't think that you have to be worried about the size of the apk since the unused resources will be stripped anyway from the apk. Just use something like https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: Really? And when does this stripping happens? Is there a Google documentation for this?

Comment: The stripping will happen on unused code, if you use proguard.

Comment: @Skynet - this doesn't apply in this case, because the resources are obviously used. Just not all of then by all devices. Google Play store itself would have to do this sort of resource stripping on the fly when downloading the app, because only at that point it is known the type of device that the apk is installed on.

Comment: [I guess this is the way to go](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

Comment: I did mention **Unused Code**

Answer (score 0):

create a drawable folder in res folder of project and paste all images there...it will resize all images according to device size

Comment: Well, this is a default. Which is not good for me, since i want 10 inch mdpi tablets to use hdpi images

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a set of resources called `icon_text.png`; and you place one in the `drawable-xxhdpi` folder and another one in `drawable-hdpi` folder. That is your scenario, right? Any device that is `mdpi` (it doesn't matter its size) will pull resources (if available) from the `hdpi` folder. The system will pick the closest match, and `mdpi` is closer to `hdpi` than to `xxhdpi`.

Comment: No, my goal is to have only one `icon_text.png` to keep the app as small as possible.

Comment: Please be so kind to explain the downvote. I don't just put answers out there without verifying them. I specifically created an application and placed a couple of icons in the xxhdpi and hdpi folder. I ran the application on a mdpi emulator and the hdpi resource was picked up. If there's something that I missed, please share.

Comment: I have a lot of images, like 20. All of them are inside `xxhdpi` folder Everything works correctly. The only case is 10 inch tablets with 800x1280 pixels. Since it is 160 dpi everything looks small. If I make `drawable-sw720dp-mdpi`and put there `hdpi` images, it solves my problem, but the size of the apk goes up, which is not an option.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. You want to use hdpi resources without having hdpi resources?

Comment: If you don't want your drawables to be scaled maybe place them in the `drawable-nodpi` folder

Comment: If you put images inside xxhdpi (well, any drawable folder) they are scaled automatically by the Android OS to fit current dpi. I mean, as long as quality of a scaled image is ok for you, you can use only one image.

Comment: Yes, I know. And that is what you are doing. You have all the images in the xxhdpi folder. And you are saying that for one particular device type (10"/mdpi) that doesn't work well. You have 2 choices: a) create special images for that particular type; b) don't scale the image.

Comment: Neither of them fits :) Guess i will try [making two different apks](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) Thank you, anyway!